# Showing that for all $f: X \to Y$ there exists $S, g: X \to S, h: S \to Y$ with $g$ injective and $h$ surjective such that $f = h \circ g$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

I want to show the claim in the title: That for all functions $f: X \to Y$ there exists some set $S$, some injective function $g: X \to S$, and some surjective function $h: S \to Y$ such that $f = h \circ g$.

So far, my line of thought is

- Maybe we can set $h$ to be the identity function (which is surjective). and $g$ to be $f$. However, this is not necessarily valid, as $f$ is not guaranteed to be injective.

Any ideas as to how to proceed?

$\ne$ [Every function $f$ can be factored into $f = i \circ s$, with $i$ injective and $s$ surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375300/)

Comment: @AnneBauval This looks like a different question to me -- the other one was asking for a factorization with $g$ surjective and $h$ injective, and this one is the other way around.

Comment: For a hint on this one: maybe you could try something with a disjoint union, $S = X \sqcup Y$.

Comment: rot13 ( t vf gur vapyhfvba, u vf gur shapgvba juvpu npgf nf s ba gur K cneg naq gur vqragvgl ba gur L cneg )

Comment: Yesssss! Thanks

Comment: I can see somebody (@QiaochuYuan perhaps?) voted to close as a duplicate of the question the OP linked to. It is a mistake, as explained in Daniel's first comment above.

Comment: Same message to @KurtG.

Comment: Same message to @amWhy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have posed the question the wrong way around, but either way, this is true, but the factorisation is not that interesting, simply define

$S = (X\times \{0\}) \cup (Y\times \{1\})$

And then define

\begin{align}
g:&X\to S\\
&x\mapsto (x,0)
\end{align}

And then define

\begin{align}
h:&S\to Y \\
h((a,n))& = \begin{cases}
  f(a) & \text{ if } n=0 \\
  a & \text{ if }n= 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I'll leave it to you to check that the conditions are satisfied

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is empty, then let $S=Y$ with $g=f$ and $h=\operatorname{id}_Y$. Then, $f=h \circ g$ with $g$ and $h$ being injective and surjective respectively.

Otherwise, let $S=X \times Y$ with $g(x)=(x,f(x))$ and $h(x,y)=y$. Then, again $f=h \circ g$ with $g$ and $h$ being injective and surjective respectively. Note that the surjectivity of $h$ requires $X$ to be nonempty.